# Need help solving this method chaining question?

Tags: javascript

I got asked this in an Interview and I couldn't solve it. Was wondering if any of you guys can help me.

```
fn("hello").fn("world").fn("!!!").fn();

function fn (str){
  // Enter Solution Here
}
```

The solution should return 'hello world !!!'.

I tried method chaining and was able to get a partially right answer which is as follows:

```js
function fn(str) {
    var string = str;
    this.fn1 = function(str1) {
        string += " "+str1;
        return this;
    }
    this.fn = function() {
        console.log(string)
    }
}

new fn("hello").fn1("world").fn1("!!!").fn();
```

but as you can see I cant get it to work unless I use fn1 as the function to concat the string. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does the original question really ask for *two* functions (`fn` and `fn1`)? What is the intended difference between the two?

Comment: At the top you don't use `new`, but in your attempt you use `new`... which is the one that is needed?

Comment: Is console suppose to be inside the function?

Comment: It was an error from my part. the original has to be  fn("hello").fn("world").fn("!!!").fn();. I updated it. also yes the new was added by me as I was trying to solve it. the original problem doesnt ask for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the function return an object with one `fn` method. If, when you call it, it has an argument, update the string, otherwise return the string so you can log it.

```js
function fn(str = '') {
  return {
    fn: function (s) {
      if (s) {
        str += ` ${s}`;
        return this;
      }
      return str;
    }
  };
}

const output = fn('hello').fn('world').fn('!!!').fn();
console.log(output);
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: _"cant get it to work unless I use fn1"_: seems like the question was "how do I do this without a separate function?", but I may have mid-read it.

Comment: @Andy It was an error from my part and I have now corrected it. the original function call doesnt have fn1.

Answer (score 1):

You could return an object with two properties, one for returning the complete string and another for collecting parts and retuning the object.

```js
function fn(str) {
    const
        fns = {
            fn: function () {
                return str;
            },
            fn1: function (s) {
                str += ' ' + s;
                return fns;
            }
        };
    return fns;
}

console.log(fn("hello").fn1("world").fn1("!!!").fn());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```js
function fn(s){
  return new function(){
     this.str = s;
     this.fn = (ns) => {if(ns){this.str += " "+ns; return this;} else return this.str;};
  }
}


let a = fn("hello").fn("world").fn("!!!").fn(); 
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Can please you explain how this solution works for my understanding?

Comment: the outer fn function returns an object made out of an anonymous functions prototype which stores the initial string as a property and has a method `fn` which either updates the string if a truthy value was passed to it, or returns the concatenated string if nothing/a falsy value was passed to it :)

Comment: and also if a truthy value was passed to the inner `fn` it returns itself to allow for chaining to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use objects

```
const generic = {
    "fn1":null,
    "current":"",
    "fn": () => {
     //what do you want to do with "this.current"?
    }

}
function fn(str) {
    var ret = generic;
    ret.fn1 = (wa) =>{
        var again = generic;
        again.current +=wa;
        return again;
    }
    ret.current += str;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: {
    "fn1":null,
    "current":"",
    "fn": () => {
     //what do you want to do with "this.current"?
    }

}

Comment: Well, that's my approach to solving this. That's why,

Comment: made that edit!

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object with a `.fn()` method which will
check if an argument is passed in or not to determine when to terminate the chain or continue chaining.

When no argument is sent, then it simply returns the accumulated string.

Otherwise, it calls `fn()` function again to accumulate to the string and get the next copy of the same structure as before:

```js
const result = fn("hello").fn("world").fn("!!!").fn();

console.log(result);

function fn (str){
  return { 
    fn(nextString) {
      if (nextString === undefined)
        return str;
        
      return fn(`${str} ${nextString}`);
    }
  };
}
```

Since this operation is immutable, it means each link in the chain is independent, therefore it is no problem with assigning to variables to continue with different chains:

```js
const helloWorld = fn("hello").fn("world");

const one   = helloWorld.fn("one").fn();
const two   = helloWorld.fn("two").fn();
const three = helloWorld.fn("three").fn();

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
console.log(three);

function fn (str){
  return { 
    fn(nextString) {
      if (nextString === undefined)
        return str;
        
      return fn(`${str} ${nextString}`);
    }
  };
}
```